# Mysql: count and return grouped records ​that do not exceed a certain amount

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose the following table `attendees`:

```
+----+------------+-------+
| id | var1       | var2  |
+----+------------+-------+
| 1  | 2020-05-08 | 9:00  |
+----+------------+-------+
| 2  | 2020-05-08 | 10:00 |
+----+------------+-------+
| 3  | 2020-05-07 | 11:00 |
+----+------------+-------+
| 4  | 2020-05-09 | 9:00  |
+----+------------+-------+
```

I need to count the values ​​of repeated `var1` and return only the rows of those values ​​IF the amount of repeated `var1` does not exceed 5. In the example above I need `Ids` 1 and 2.

This didn't work:

```
mysql --> SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM attendees GROUP BY var1 WHERE COUNT(*) < 5;
```

Comment: is var1 defined as DATE and var2 defined as TIME in mysql?

Comment: No. Are varchar.

Comment: you can'\t compare with VARCHAR type, they should be in their proper type as DATE and TIME

Comment: You can compare with varchar, but it might not be a brilliant idea

Comment: I don't understand if the amount exceed by 5

Comment: do you mean it should return the id only if the count is less than five ?

Comment: @Aman, yes. 5 is an external variable that I used here only as an example of the limit to be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
select var1
from attendees
group by var1 
having count(*) between 2 and 5
```

returns all the `var1`s that you want.
The requirement *does not exceed 5* means that it can't be greater than 5 but it can be equal to 5, right?
Use it like this:

```
select * from attendees
where var1 in (
  select var1
  from attendees
  group by var1 
  having count(*) between 2 and 5
)
```

Comment: It is exactly what i want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d8z8WWiupQcRAmT57ZZCV/1).

```
select
    id
from
(select
    id,
    count(*) over (partition by var1) as total
from attendees
) t
where total < 5
and total > 1
```

Output:

```
*--*
|id|
*--*
| 1| 
| 2|
*--*
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *, COUNT(var2) FROM attendees GROUP BY var1 WHERE COUNT(var2) < 5;